# uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this error if I try to push to Heroku. On production it all works fine.

If I run "rake assets:precompile" on development It works fine. When Heroku does it, it fail

**Heroku Logs**

```
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admind9c593b13a6f/lib/active_admin/application.rb:258:in `generate_stylesheets': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin



source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'devise',             github: 'plataformatec/devise',     branch: 'rails4'
gem 'responders'       ,   github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack',            branch: 'rails-4'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'akashkamboj/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'


gem "cancan"
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'carrierwave'
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/110) shed any light?

Comment: Nope. The strange thing is I'm using Rails 4.0.0

Comment: @Matt I found out It came form Active Admin. But I can't figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gem 'activeadmin',  github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
```